error: failed while building app in expo 52 after adding googleService.json file in project
i build and expo app in 52. it works fine and build until i add the firebase googleService json file in it. it shows error in run gradle.
`

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugDuplicateClasses'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.CheckDuplicatesRunnable
   > Duplicate class android.support.v4.app.INotificationSideChannel found in modules core-1.13.1.aar -> core-1.13.1-runtime (androidx.core:core:1.13.1) and support-compat-27.1.1.aar -> support-compat-27.1.1-runtime (com.android.support:support-compat:27.1.1)
     Duplicate class android.support.v4.app.INotificationSideChannel$Stub found in modules core-1.13.1.aar -> core-1.13.1-runtime (androidx.core:core:1.13.1) and support-compat-27.1.1.aar -> support-compat-27.1.1-runtime (com.android.support:support-compat:27.1.1)
     Duplicate class android.support.v4.app.INotificationSideChannel$Stub$Proxy found in modules core-1.13.1.aar -> core-1.13.1-runtime (androidx.core:core:1.13.1) and support-compat-27.1.1.aar -> support-compat-27.1.1-runtime (com.android.support:support-compat:27.1.1)
     Duplicate class android.support.v4.os.IResultReceiver found in modules core-1.13.1.aar -> core-1.13.1-runtime (androidx.core:core:1.13.1) and support-compat-27.1.1.aar -> support-compat-27.1.1-runtime (com.android.support:support-compat:27.1.1)
     Duplicate class android.support.v4.os.IResultReceiver$Stub found in modules core-1.13.1.aar -> core-1.13.1-runtime (androidx.core:core:1.13.1) and support-compat-27.1.1.aar -> support-compat-27.1.1-runtime (com.android.support:support-compat:27.1.1)
     Duplicate class android.support.v4.os.IResultReceiver$Stub$Proxy found in modules core-1.13.1.aar -> core-1.13.1-runtime (androidx.core:core:1.13.1) and support-compat-27.1.1.aar -> support-compat-27.1.1-runtime (com.android.support:support-compat:27.1.1)
     Duplicate class android.support.v4.os.ResultReceiver found in modules core-1.13.1.aar -> core-1.13.1-runtime (androidx.core:core:1.13.1) and support-compat-27.1.1.aar -> support-compat-27.1.1-runtime (com.android.support:support-compat:27.1.1)
     Duplicate class android.support.v4.os.ResultReceiver$1 found in modules core-1.13.1.aar -> core-1.13.1-runtime (androidx.core:core:1.13.1) and support-compat-27.1.1.aar -> support-compat-27.1.1-runtime (com.android.support:support-compat:27.1.1)
     Duplicate class android.support.v4.os.ResultReceiver$MyResultReceiver found in modules core-1.13.1.aar -> core-1.13.1-runtime (androidx.core:core:1.13.1) and support-compat-27.1.1.aar -> support-compat-27.1.1-runtime (com.android.support:support-compat:27.1.1)
     Duplicate class android.support.v4.os.ResultReceiver$MyRunnable found in modules core-1.13.1.aar -> core-1.13.1-runtime (androidx.core:core:1.13.1) and support-compat-27.1.1.aar -> support-compat-27.1.1-runtime (com.android.support:support-compat:27.1.1)
     
     Go to the documentation to learn how to <a href="d.android.com/r/tools/classpath-sync-errors">Fix dependency resolution errors</a>.
* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
> Get more help at https://help.gradle.org.
BUILD FAILED in 3m 41s
Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 9.0.
You can use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings and determine if they come from your own scripts or plugins.
For more on this, please refer to https://docs.gradle.org/8.10.2/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings in the Gradle documentation.
703 actionable tasks: 702 executed, 1 up-to-date
Error: Gradle build failed with unknown error. See logs for the "Run gradlew" phase for more information.`

Can anyone help me. Thank you in advance!
I tried to change the java version  from 11 to 17 , changing gradle dependencies but didnot work.
